# Python find sub string

Tags: python, split

I have a very special work to do, here is my input

```
Period End Date         12/30/    12/31/   12/29/    12/28/    12/31/2007
                         2011      2010     2009      2008
```

You can see this is a wrong input file:

1. year is on the second line
2. but last date is correct

So I want to dig out the correct date:
12/31/2011 12/31/2012 12/31/2009 12/31/2008 12/31/2007

Here is what I am trying to do

```
 input_file = open("input", "r")
 for line in input_file:
   index = line.find("Period End Date", 0)
   if index != -1:
     line = line[index+len("Period End Date"):len(line)] 
     temp_line = " ".join(line.split())
     temp_line.split(" ")

     year_line= input_file.next()
     #remove space, split,append on temp_line[i]
```

But it doesn't work:

```
temp_line.split(" ")
```

returns `['1','2','/', ...]` not `['12/31/', '12/30', ...]`

What's wrong with that?

Comment: I don't see much "special" about this, that task is average at best.

Comment: where you say  12/31/2012 do you mean 12/31/2010 ?

Comment: I mean special because date is mismatched after html2text, anyway, it's a bug.
It's just an example, it doesn't matter 2012 or 2010. The problem is after split(), it returns '1', '2', '/'... how to get '12/31/'?

Comment: What is the point of this? __" ".join(line.split())__ you split a line to join it again

Comment: @campos.ddc: That line alone would even make some sense (replacing any amount of whitespace with just one space), but combined with the following line it *would be* really pointless, but in fact the next line also doesn't work as expected.

Comment: It's okay, i use this to remove spaces between keywords.

Comment: @campos.ddc: gets rid of double spaces

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at your code:

```
temp_line = " ".join(line.split())
```

This replaces multiple whitespace with one single space. So far, so okay. Next line:

```
temp_line.split(" ")
```

Now what? Splitting it again at single space? This only reverses the join you've done before. Why didn't you just stick with `line.split()`, then? Also, you're not assigning the result back to `temp_line`, so the result is *discarded*, which is probably the main issue here.

You could use something like that instead:

```
 with open("input", "rb") as f:
   lines = list(f)
   for date_line, year_line in zip(lines, lines[1:])[::2]:
     parts = date_line.strip().split()
     if ' '.join(parts[0:3]) != 'Period End Date': continue

     dates, years = parts[3:], year_line.strip().split()[1:]
     year_index = 0
     for date in dates:
       if not date.split('/')[-1]:
         date = date + years[year_index]
         year_index += 1
       print date
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to presume that the number of dates varies, but always consists of N day-month entries, followed by a complete day-month-year entry, followed by N year entries:

```
def getHeadings(s):
    head = s.split()
    num_dates = (len(head) - 4)/2
    return [dm+y for dm,y in zip(head[3:3+num_dates], head[4+num_dates:])] + head[3+num_dates:4+num_dates]

getHeadings("""    Period End Date 12/30/ 12/31/ 12/29/ 12/28/ 12/31/2007

                        2011      2010     2009      2008""")
```

returns

```
['12/30/2011', '12/31/2010', '12/29/2009', '12/28/2008', '12/31/2007']
```

Answer (score 0):

it works

```
>>> temp_line = " ".join(line.split())
>>> temp_line
'12/30/ 12/31/ 12/29/ 12/28/ 12/31/2007'
>>> temp_line.split(" ")
['12/30/', '12/31/', '12/29/', '12/28/', '12/31/2007']
```

if you are iterating over each item in `temp_line` then you will get '1','2','/'... etc.

Also, may I suggest some pythonic adjustments to your code? use `line.split('Period End Date ')[1].strip().split(" ")` instead of

```
line = line[index+len("Period End Date"):len(line)] 
temp_line = " ".join(line.split())
temp_line.split(" ")
```

Plus `file` is an iterator in python you can simply do -

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        <do something with line>
```

The `with` statement handles opening and closing the file, including if an exception is raised in the inner block. The `for line in f` treats the file object f as an iterable, which automatically uses buffered IO

Comment: Yes you are right, I do iterate each item and  get 1 , 2, /...
but how can I get '12/30/' from  temp_line?

Comment: simple. try - `for string in temp_line: <process string>`

Comment: I think `line.split('Period End Date ')[1].strip().split()` would be the correct equivalent to the original code.

Comment: @Srikar: Not quite. It's gotta be `split()` whithout an argument to do the same thing as the original code.

Comment: @Srikar, line.split('Period End Date ')[1].strip().split() is right but the problem is this input file contains other format lines, I'll have to read the next line getting year info when one line matches "Period End Date" at the beginning. If not, I'll just read one line. That's why I implement my codes in the C/C++ way. Do you have any suggestions in pythonic way? thanks

Comment: actually in python default arg for `split` is whitespace. So specifying split(" ") is kinda redundant. `split() == split(" ")` they are same.

Comment: @Srikar: No, [`'asd\tasd'.split() != 'asd\tasd'.split(' ')`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). Also works with multiple spaces as separators, so `'asd__asd'.split() != 'asd__asd'.split(' ')`, with underscore representing a space here for formatting.

Comment: >>> 'asd__asd'.split() == 'asd__asd'.split(' ')
True . But i see what you are saying.

Comment: @Srikar: Obviously you have to replace the underscores with spaces, like I said...